# cannot invoke 'getObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I am receiving the following error:

> cannot invoke 'getObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument list of type

with the following line of code:

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("Parse Object id is here")
```

the full line of code is:

```
func CallData(){
       var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsandAnswers")
       query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("Parse Object id is here") {
            (ObjectHolder : PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                self.Question = ObjectHolder.valueForKey("Question") as! String
                self.Answers = ObjectHolder.valueForKey("Answers") as! Array
                self.Answer = ObjectHolder.valueForKey("Answer") as! String

                if(self.Answers.count > 0){
                    self.QuestionLabel.text = self.Question

                }
```

Anyone have any advice? I am using xcode7

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 2, the method signature has changed for this method.

Use the following:

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("Parse Object id is here") {
        (ObjectHolder: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            self.Question = ObjectHolder.valueForKey("Question") as! String
            self.Answers = ObjectHolder.valueForKey("Answers") as! Array
            self.Answer = ObjectHolder.valueForKey("Answer") as! String

            if(self.Answers.count > 0){
                self.QuestionLabel.text = self.Question
            }
```

See [doc here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-retrieving-objects).